# How to generate a Pdf in Land Scape orientation from a html string using Itext 2

Tags: flying-saucer

I am using this code to generate a PDF from HTML String.

```
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocumentFromString(new String(htmlString.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

In table some row contains data of a very large length.Due to which the text is overflowing the PDF.I have used Word Wrap in HTML.But this is not working in PDF generated by the code.
I want to know if there is any alternative in IText 2 to Word Wrap?

Or can i generate my PDF in Landscape Mode so that i could display the whole data in PDF.

Any suggestion is welcomed.

I have attached one image at following URL. 
http://www.mediafire.com/download/l19qa33myluaqj4/pw-4_(2).jpg

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can set your page in landscape mode using CSS, using:

```
@page { size: A4 landscape;}
```

The page size is part of [CSS 3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#page-size), and is supported by flying saucer.

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer as suggested by @Bruno Lowagie

We can set our page in landscape mode using CSS, using:

```
@page { size: A4 landscape;}
```